# What order do I watch the Tenchi anime in?

Tags: tenchi-multiverse

I'm trying to watch the anime series *Tenchi* and don't know what order to watch the episodes in, including the OVAs and movies. What order are they intended to be watched in?

Comment: I'm not sure this is exactly a duplicate of that one (this one asks for viewing order, while that one asks for the in-universe chronology), but it's certainly highly relevant.

Comment: @LoganM I do think they are strongly related. But there the question is how are they related. Although it answer this question aswell I think people prefer to see some list over a massive wall of text.

Comment: @LoganM: Perhaps, but this question is answered there.

Answer (score 1):

Theres are allot of story pieces involved. But one of the easyest ways to decide in which order to watch would be by [checking out this website](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=rel&aid=409). It has the storys and their time settings layed down in detail (this might be a good addition to the [How are tenchi timelines related](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2089/how-are-the-tenchi-timelines-related))

For a casual viewing order you should watch it in this order

- Tenchi Muyou! Ryououki (1992-1993)
- Tenchi Muyou! Ryououki Omatsuri Zen `y.... (1993)
- Tenchi Muyou! Ryououki (1994)
- Tenchi Muyou! Ryououki (2003)

Then you can follow this up by the side story about his parents

- Tenchi Muyou! Bangaihen: Galaxy Police (1994)
- Mahou Shoujo Pretty Sammy (1995- 1997)

And from here on out you can either go check out alternative settings

- Shin Tenchi Muyou! (1997)
- Tenchi Muyou! Manatsu no Eve (1997)
- Tenchi Muyou! (1995)

Or even the alternative version of  the side story

- Mahou Shoujo Pretty sammy (1996)

And the alternative version settings variant of this

- Sasami: Mahou Shoujo Club (2006)
- Sasami: Mahou Shoujo Club 2 (2006-2007)

And finally you can check out the Same setting story

- Tenchi Muyou! GXP (2002)
- Isekai no Seikishi Monogatari ( 2009-2010)
- Dual! Parallel Runrun Monogatari

With this info it is pretty much up to yourself how to actually watch it. But for story purposes I would advice at least watching the first 4 I stated in that order.